# Debugging with Eclipse CDT and GDB: can't find source file

Tags: eclipse, configuration, ide, eclipse-cdt

When I try to debug my application using GDB from eclipse CDT, I get the following error:

```
 Can't find a source file at "../mingw/main.c"
 Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

Eclipse is looking for the source file location at ../mingw/main.c, but it should be in /edit/src/main.c. As you can see in the screenshot below, edit/src is part of the source lookup path. Why is looking in ../mingw? I can't find any configuration setting that makes it look there.

[image: Here is a screenshot that indicates the problem]

I'm using eclipse Juno, CDT 8.1, Windows 7 64bit

Comment: did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: I need to find an answer to this question as well.

Comment: No, I still don't know what the solution is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your answer http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/57027/

If you're working under Windows, have you set the required mappings?
Maybe Eclipse couldn't find the Source because of the missing mapping to
the (cygwin-)drive where your projects/workspaces are.

When you start Cygwin, enter "mount" and look for the mapping you have:
They may look like this:

```
Admin@bs11-01xp ~
$ mount
D:\cygwin\bin on /usr/bin type system (binmode)
D:\cygwin\lib on /usr/lib type system (binmode)
D:\cygwin on / type system (binmode)
c: on /cygdrive/c type system (binmode,noumount)
d: on /cygdrive/d type system (binmode,noumount)
e: on /cygdrive/e type system (binmode,noumount)
j: on /cygdrive/j type system (binmode,noumount)
n: on /cygdrive/n type system (binmode,noumount)
u: on /cygdrive/u type system (binmode,noumount)
w: on /cygdrive/w type system (binmode,noumount)
x: on /cygdrive/x type system (binmode,noumount)
y: on /cygdrive/y type system (binmode,noumount)
z: on /cygdrive/z type system (binmode,noumount)
```

My Projects ara all under `J:\Projects`, so my mapping needs to be present
in Eclipse as:

```
/cygdrive/j j:/
```

Open Eclipse and then click
- Windows => Preferences... => C/C++ => Debug =>Common Source Lookup
Path
- Add a new Path Mapping: click [Add] => Path Mapping => [OK]
- Select the new Mapping => [Edith] => change Name of Mapping "Project
Source" => [Add]
- set "Compilation path" to the Source (Sample cygwin!) "/cygdrive/j"
(without the quotes!)
- set"Local file system path" tho "J:\" (without the quotes!)

Now you are ready ti give it another try.... good luck !

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. The links may get relocated/deleted. Please edit the answer to include the actual steps as well (in addition to the link).

Answer (score 0):

in "Debug Configuration" (under debugger popup icon) in Debugger tab uncheck "stop on startup at", after this it will not stop on startup, but u can put breakpoint there if u like

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works. No solution as above worked except below

I simply replaced gdb with msys gdb

ie. for example

current configuration

... Application Configuration .. Debug .. Debug

GDB Debugger              gdb

to

GDB Debugger       path to msys gdb (like for example c:\msys\bin\gdb.exe

Manu

Comment: Instead of copy/paste your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70863243/10952503), why don't make it linked with the question and more explain why and how this fix the issue ?